# extracting a log file which has xml in it

Tags: php, regex

I have a log file whose content is like the one below

```
2016-04-07 19:37:48 <order merchant="asc" affiliate="" id="UM9E-C01101518" date="1443723720" event_id="1" ref="GDVJT" alias="asc">
 <event type="sale" date="2015-10-01 18:22:00" status_code="SA">
   <sale amount="61.45" amount_usd="43.94" method="VISA" currency="CAD" processor="visa"/>
   <tax amount="7.37" amount_usd="5.28" currency="CAD"/>
   <payout amount="39.89" currency="USD"/>
 </event>
 <customer>
   <name>Frank</name>
   <email>frank@gmail.com</email>
   <address/>
   <region>BC</region>
   <country>IN</country>
   <zip_postal>V8V1J9</zip_postal>
   <phone_number>1231231234</phone_number>
   <language>EN</language>
   <ip>209.13.233.227</ip>
   <currency>CAD</currency>
 </customer>
```

I am trying to extract the value of name and email from this log file.
I am using the below code:

```
$handle = fopen('vendorOrder.log','r') or die ('File opening failed');
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $dd = fgets($handle);
    $str = htmlentities($dd, ENT_XHTML);

    if(preg_match("/<name>(.*)<\/name>/",$str)){
        $txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "name");
        echo $txt; 
    }



}
fclose($handle);

function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

But it is never matching the name tag and I am not able to get the value between the tags.
I need the output as Frank.
Can someone let me know whats wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `simplexml_load_file()` php function.
Example:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("vendorOrder.log") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

And get this value with `$xml->customer->name`

Maybe your XML are crashed. Try this format.

```html
<order merchant="asc" affiliate="" id="UM9E-C01101518" date="1443723720" event_id="1" ref="GDVJT" alias="asc">
 <event type="sale" date="2015-10-01 18:22:00" status_code="SA">
   <sale amount="61.45" amount_usd="43.94" method="VISA" currency="CAD" processor="visa"/>
   <tax amount="7.37" amount_usd="5.28" currency="CAD"/>
   <payout amount="39.89" currency="USD"/>
 </event>
 <customer>
   <datetime>2016-04-07 19:37:48</datetime>
   <name>Frank</name>
   <email>frank@gmail.com</email>
   <address/>
   <region>BC</region>
   <country>IN</country>
   <zip_postal>V8V1J9</zip_postal>
   <phone_number>1231231234</phone_number>
   <language>EN</language>
   <ip>209.13.233.227</ip>
   <currency>CAD</currency>
 </customer>
</order>
```

Comment: Its a response log file from the payment gateway and not able to format

Answer (score 0):

Yup as stated use simplexml_load_file($url) ; to parse xml.

you can find examples here : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp

Comment: Its a log file and not xml . Its a response I am getting from the payment gateway and not able to change

Comment: that has nothing to do with file type its about content

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_file(): vendorOrder.log:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found . This is the error I am getting as the log file starts with date and not tags

Comment: gotcha , remove it with regex or str functions and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a correction in original string with something like this:

```php
<?php
$xml_file = 'vendorOrder.log';
$xml_content = file_get_contents( $xml_file );
$xml_content .= "\n</order>";
$xml_content = substr( $xml_content, 20 );
var_dump($xml_content);

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xml_content) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->customer->name;
```

Comment: Got this error- Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found

Comment: I do this same test here and goes right. You changed the XML file? You just need correc the file removing the data in the begging of your file, and add </order> in the last line. Look the var_dump() response, and put more or less chars to cut in substr(); maybe your file needs 21 or 19 to stay in the pattern.